# Symfony 4 - Don't load DataFixtures in production

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

In production, DoctrineFixturesBundle isn't present, so when Symfony tries to register my DataFixtures classes it will throw an error.

This is what I've tried, but it seems like Symfony is ignoring services_prod.yaml, or it's not correctly overriding the config.

config/services.yaml

```
services:
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Exception,Migrations,Test,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

config/services_prod.yaml

```
services:
    # Override default to exclude DataFixtures
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DataFixtures,Entity,Exception,Migrations,Test,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

Any ideas on how I can get Symfony to not register the DataFixtures classes as services in production?

Comment: I think you have to do the opposite and exclude DataFixtures in your `services.yaml` by default and then in `services_dev.yaml` and `services_test.yaml` include it.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure if the bundle is allowed in both enviroments, see the config/bundles.php

```
Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['all' => true]
```

Or

```
Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'prod' => true]
```